# VSTO Outlook Attach to an event on folder creation

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

Every time a folder is manually created by the user I need to subscribe to some folder events such as ItemAdd.So how can I handle when a new folder is created and then subscribe to its events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Folders.FolderAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.folderadd) event which is available in the Outlook object model and which is fired when a folder is added to the specified `Folders` collection. The `Folder` that is added is passed as a parameter, so you can subscribe to the `ItemAdd` event instantly.

See [FoldersEvents_Event.FolderAdd Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.foldersevents_event.folderadd?view=outlook-pia) for more information.